# jQuery Ajax not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I have function:

```
$(function () {
                    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'conf/send.php',
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            success: function () {
                                var form = document.getElementById("Form");
                                form.submit();
                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
               });
```

In FF, Chrome, Opera, IE work good. In Safari not work.
Tried to add:

```
async: false,

$.ajaxSetup({
  type: 'POST',
  headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
   options.data = jQuery.param($.extend(originalOptions.data||{}, { 
     timeStamp: new Date().getTime()
   }));
});
```

It did not help that could be done?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this code:

```
success: function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("Form");
    form.submit();
}
```

Is actually what you want? You're telling JavaScript that if your form sends via AJAX, it should then send the form with id of `#Form`. Perhaps you should try this:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('form');

    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'conf/send.php',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //var form = document.getElementById("Form");
                //form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why did you answer exactly the same way I did?

Comment: That's right, I write the form data, and then send a request. I checked your version does not work.

Comment: @Kyra I begun writing my answer before you posted yours. Arguably there are some differences between our code, such as my use of caching, but yeah, you did beat me to it.

Comment: <form method="post"  name="Form" id="Form" action= "https://www.examle.com">  <button type="button" name="submitform" style="border: 0; background: transparent" onClick="return validateForm();"><img src="img/button.png"  alt="submit" /> </button> </form>

Comment: Sorry, already found, have wrong type: type="button" -> type="submit". Thanks

Comment: In that HTML, nothing can be posted, because you have no input/button fields with values inside of your form. Also, what does `validateForm()` do? Because as far as I see, there is no way to submit your form, ie. `<button type="submit"` or `<input type="submit">`. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pgqmb/, and see the changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get stuck in a loop as you `form.submit()` on `success()`

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'conf/send.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
        }).done(function(response){ 
            alert(response);
            return true; 
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKPq5/